# Downgrading nVidia driver problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, downgrade

I have been experiencing the bug mentioned [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/973096). People have reported downgrading their driver to 290.10 prevented the issue for them so I tried this but I am not sure whether I have installed the driver right as I am still experiencing the problem.

---

I went [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/nvidia-current/290.10-0ubuntu2) and downloaded the .deb, then to install it I ran:

`sudo dpkg -i nvidia-current_290.10-0ubuntu2_i386.deb`

There were no error messages from dpkg.

I checked in the Synaptic Package Manager that the install version was 290.10-0ubuntu2 which it is so I locked it to this version.

The reason I question whether I have installed it correctly is because in the nvidia-settings it still shows the driver version as 295.49?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it installs correctly. but nvidia-settings is not recognizing the change.

You can verify this by running this command : `dpkg -l nvidia-current` to see the exact version number installed

Comment: I was hoping I hadn't installed it correctly because I am fed up of these crashes but it seems I have :/ Thank you anyway.